# How can allowed to enter the sign > in the input tag with the type number?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, input

I have an input box and my wish is to be able to allow the user to enter a greater than sign along with numbers after the condition here that only the > sign and digits are allowed.
[image]

How can I validate it in this case?

Comment: What kind of number starts with ">"? If you really want to do that, you're better off adding a JS event listener that prevents all but digits and ">".

Comment: It's a special case, can you help me write a function to do that @kmoser ?

Answer (score 3):

A big reason for the existence of an input of type number is so that the user can enter *only* numbers, not a random `>` symbol. You can create a workaround by using a regular input that relies on JavaScript (via the `keypress` event) to filter what contents are allowed.

Given you're using React, here's an example:

```js
const App = () => {
  return (
    <input onKeyPress={e => {
      if(!/[\d>]/.test(e.key)) e.preventDefault()
    }} placeholder="type a number or &quot;>&quot;" />
  )
}

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root")).render(<App />)
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: This allows ">" after a digit. Should that be allowed?

Comment: @kmoser the OP only said that `">"` and digits should be allowed, but didn't specify that the symbol must be the first input character, so given the user's response I'm guessing yes.